# Python function attribute cannot get data

Tags: python

I design a python program
I save and set 5 kinds of fruits in the dictionary
Then enter the 5 kinds of fruits, the favorite 1 kind of fruit
Then determine the number of items

```
Example:

    fruit={"apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","peach"}
```

I type banana
Print result immediately: Banana is in item 2
If i enter cherry
Because cherries are not in the fruit dictionary
Print results immediately
Cherries are not in the list!
But there is an error in my python program execution:

```
if fruit.get(frus)==None:
AttributeError:'set' object has no attribute'get'
```

I hope everyone can give some assistance and guidance

I hope to achieve

```
fruit={"apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","orange"}
Please enter the fruit you like (Enter ends): Banana
The second item in the list of bananas
with
  fruit={"apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","orange"}
Please enter your favorite fruit (End of Enter): Cherry
Cherries are not in the list!
```

My code:

```
fruit={"apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","orange"}
frus=input("Please input the fruit you like (End of Enter):")
if fruit.get(frus)==None:
     print(str(frus),"not in the list!")
else:
     ans=fruit.count(frus)
     print(ans)
```

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: That's not a dictionary, it's a set. A dictionary looks like `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`

Comment: That's a set, not a dictionary. Did you mean to make a dictionary? If so, what should the keys and values be? What is your data structure intended to represent?

Comment: With a set you use `if frus not in fruit:`

Comment: Just a small comment - generally instead of ==None , is None is more elegant - but everyone above is right fruit is a set not a dictionary therefore it has no .get() method

Comment: I understand the solution to this problem,
Thank you everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the `fruit` variable is a `set`, not a `dict`. but that doesn't seem wrong in that situation. all you need to do is fix the logic in the if statement to check if `frus` is in the set `fruit`:

```py
fruit = {"apple", "banana", "guava", "lotus mist", "orange"}
frus = input("Please input the fruit you like (End of Enter):")
if frus not in fruit:
     print(frus, "not in the list!")
else:
     ans = fruit.count(frus) # this line won't work and I don't know what you were trying to do.
     print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a `set`, not a `dict`.  This is more like what you want to do:

```py
fruit={"apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","orange"}
frus=input("Please input the fruit you like (End of Enter):")
if frus not in fruit:
     print(frus+" not in the list!")
else:
     ans=fruit.count(frus)
     print(ans)
```

**Notes:**

1. I removed `str(frus)` because `input` returns a `str` anyways.
2. Your `fruit.count` function will return the number of times that the value of `frus` appears in the `set` (not what you wanted).  Since `set`s are unordered, there is not unique index of any given element.  What you might want is that `fruit` be a `list`:

```py
fruit=["apple","banana","guava","lotus mist","orange"]
frus=input("Please input the fruit you like (End of Enter):")
if frus not in fruit:
     print(frus.capitalize()+" is not in the list!")
else:
     ans=fruit.index(frus)+1
     print(frus+" is item "+str(ans)+" in the list.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possible advantages for maintaining a `set` data object, others for a list. Here's a solution which shows a flexible interoperability between the two:

```py
fruit = {"apple", "banana", "guava", "lotus mist", "orange"}

x = 'banana'

def get_from_set(my_set,x):
    if x in my_set:
        return x
    else:
        return None

if get_from_set(fruit, x):
    print(f'Your favorite fruit {x} appears {list(fruit).count(x)} times')
else:
    print(f'{x} not found in fruit')
```

*Transforming `fruit` to a list allows you to utilize python's built in `count` method – however, a set will not contain duplicate values, so the count will always be `1`.*